# Formatting selectInput() to show character dates to the user

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently building a shiny app and trying to get a set of dates to render as character strings to the end user, while still keeping their date format when invoked in the server side code.

There might be a simple solution here, but unsure how to get the dates to format in the selectInput dropdown. In my actual use case, using a date slider isn't ideal as the dates do not follow a common interval.

Reproducible example below:

```
# setup
require(lubridate)
test.dates <- as.Date(c('2014-06-01', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-01',     
                        '2014-09-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-11-01',  
                        '2014-12-01', '2015-01-01','2015-02-01', 
                        '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01'))
test.names <- as.character(paste0(month(test.dates, label = T), ' ', 
                                  year(test.dates)))
test.df <- data.frame(date = test.dates)
row.names(test.df) <- test.names

# shiny
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$table <- renderTable(test.df)

}


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("test", label = "DATE FORMAT TEST:", choices =   
                  test.df, selected = test.df[1,])
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput('table'))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Using the suggestion from @cdeterman below, when I use a `list` or `array` instead of a `data.frame`, the UI rendering of the character dates renders as the name of the array element instead of the value which is great.   `my.list <- setNames(test.dates, test.names)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will find it much easier to pass around `character` objects than `date` objects in Shiny.  I would simply use the direct `character` values of your dates and whenever you need them to be `date` objects in your subsequent analysis explicitly convert to a `date` object.  The following provides an example where both the dropdown and table have the character formatted dates.

```
require(lubridate)
myDates <- c('2014-06-01', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-01',     
             '2014-09-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-11-01',  
             '2014-12-01', '2015-01-01','2015-02-01', 
             '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01')
test.names <- as.character(paste0(lubridate::month(test.dates, label=TRUE), ' ', 
                                  year(test.dates)))
test.df <- data.frame(date = myDates)
row.names(test.df) <- test.names

# shiny
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderTable(test.df)

}


ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("test", label = "DATE FORMAT TEST:", choices =   
                            myDates, selected = myDates[1])
        ),
        mainPanel(tableOutput('table'))
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems a lot easier.  Was hoping to avoid the in-analysis conversion as it gets a bit more confusing reading through code, but not a big deal.  I was hoping there may be some workaround related to using a named list, but I couldn't get it to work.